# EF 5 composite key with a Many relationship to other entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In the following code, I use EF code first to setup my database model.

The CaseCommunication entity has a composite key including an Id column. If I let EF do the work, it tries to use this column as a FK to the other entity despite a Many() specification:

```
HasRequired(x => x.Case).WithMany(x => x.Communications);
HasOptional(x => x.FirstReadBy).WithMany();
```

To get a correct model I have to explicitly setup the FK (please read the comments in the code).

```
HasRequired(x => x.Case).WithMany(x => x.Communications).Map(x => x.MapKey("Case_Id"));
HasOptional(x => x.FirstReadBy).WithMany().Map(x => x.MapKey("FirstReadBy_Id"));
```

If I do not use a composite key, then all works correctly without using Map().

My question is: what is the logic of EF ? Or said another way, what am I missing?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace testef {
    //Model
    public partial class Case {
        public Case() {                
            Communications = new List<CaseCommunication>();
        }
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CaseCommunication> Communications { get; set; }
    }

    public class CaseCommunication  {

        public String CComType { get; set; }
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Case Case { get; set; }

        public virtual User FirstReadBy { get; set; }
    }

    public class User {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    }

    //Configuration for CObj
    public class UserEFCFConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User> {
        public UserEFCFConfiguration()
            : base() {
            ToTable("Users", "dbo");
            HasKey(x => x.Id);
            Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        }
    }

    public class CaseEFCFConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Case> {
        public CaseEFCFConfiguration()
            : base() {
            ToTable("Cases", "dbo");
            HasKey(x => x.Id);
            Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);   
        }
    }

    public class CaseCommunicationEFCFConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CaseCommunication> {
        public CaseCommunicationEFCFConfiguration()
            : base() {
            ToTable("VCaseCommunications", "dbo");
            Property(x => x.CComType).HasColumnType("char").HasMaxLength(2);

            HasKey(x => new { x.CComType, x.Id });

            // OK
            HasRequired(x => x.Case).WithMany(x => x.Communications).Map(x => x.MapKey("Case_Id"));
            HasOptional(x => x.FirstReadBy).WithMany().Map(x => x.MapKey("FirstReadBy_Id"));

            // KO
            //HasRequired(x => x.Case).WithMany(x => x.Communications);
            //HasOptional(x => x.FirstReadBy).WithMany()
            //EF tries to use the x.Id as FK for both Case and FirstReadBy
            //For FirstReadBy this leads to a Model error as x.Id is not nullable
            //But in each case I can't understand how EF expect to give the many relation by using a part of the PK as FK

            // OK
            //HasKey(x => x.Id);
            //HasRequired(x => x.Case).WithMany(x => x.Communications);
            //HasOptional(x => x.FirstReadBy).WithMany()
        }
    }

    public class TestEFContext : DbContext {
        public IDbSet<Case> Cases { get; set; }

        public TestEFContext(String cs)
            : base(cs) {
            Database.SetInitializer<TestEFContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestEFContext>());
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserEFCFConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CaseEFCFConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CaseCommunicationEFCFConfiguration());
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(String[] args) {
            String cs = @"Data Source=ALIASTVALK;Initial Catalog=TestEF;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True";                

            using (TestEFContext c = new TestEFContext(cs)) {
                Console.WriteLine(c.Cases.Count());
            }                                                                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact this seems to be the default behavior of EF: if a part of the linked entity key has the same name as the referenced entity PK, then this so named property is used as a FK.